# Error while fetching data from MySql Database in python

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter, passwords, where-clause

I am trying to fetch password from Mysql database using WHERE clause in Python and storing the password in a variable "DbPassword" but when I am printing the "DbPassword" it prints "None"
can anyone explain why this is happening and how can I solve this?
Thank you [I have attached a ScreenShot of my IDE where the entire function and Output can be seen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qf60u.png)

```
def searchdb(self):        
    User = (self.Username.get())
    pas = (self.Password.get())
   
    myconn = mysql.connector.connect(host = "localhost", user = "root", passwd = "qwerty321", database = "admin")
    
    if len(User) == 0 and len(pas) == 0 :
       tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Pharmacy Management System","Please fill in the Login Details")
    elif len(User) == 0 and len(pas) != 0 :
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Pharmacy Management System","Please Enter a Username")
    elif len(User) != 0 and len(pas) == 0:
         tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Pharmacy Management System","Please enter a Password")
    else:
        try:
            #seacrch data
            #print("%s\n%s"%(User,pas) )
            
            sql = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE user_name = '%s'"
            cur = myconn.cursor()
            cur.execute(sql,(User))
           
            DbPassword = cur.fetchone()
            
            print("%s"%(DbPassword))
            
            if (pas == str(DbPassword)) :
                self.btnRegistration.config(state=NORMAL)
                self.btnHospital.config(state=NORMAL)
            else:
                tkinter.messagebox.askokcancel("Pharmacy Management System","You have entered an invalid login details")
                self.btnRegistration.config(state=DISABLED)
                self.btnHospital.config(state=DISABLED)
                self.Username.set("")
                self.Password.set("")
                self.txtUsername.focus()
        except Error as e:
               # tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Pharmacy Management System","NO RECORD FOUND !")
                myconn.rollback()
                Window1.Reset(self)
    myconn.close()
```

Comment: Can you add `print(e)` to the except block, and [edit] the question with the output please?

Comment: What is `User` and try this `cur.execute(sql,(User,))`

Comment: @snakecharmerb added print(e) no change in output, I have uploaded a screenshot please have a look.

Comment: @CoolCloud User' is the UserName which is entered at the time of login, using this 'User' the database is searched whether the 'User' is registered or not. 'pas' is also the password entered at the time of login ''pas' will be compared with the password stored in the database that is fetched and stored in DbPassword.

Comment: Also you can remove the `''` like `sql = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE user_name = %s"`

Comment: @CoolCloud no it is User = self.UserName.get() UserName is in other function and it is working perfectly.

Comment: try `print(User)` and make sure it is what you want it to be, and then maybe proceed.

Comment: `print(User)` is working fine and giving the output as expected. As you can see in the code  `print("%s\n%s"%(User,pas) )` to print the UserName and Password entered is working fine.

Comment: Try `sql = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE user_name = %s"` and `cur.execute(sql, (User,))`.

Comment: After `sql = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE user_name = %s" and cur.execute(sql, (User,))` I got this error

mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'username''' at line 1

Comment: Which have you used `username` (in the error) or `user_name` in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally **got the answer** made some changes
modified:

```
sql = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE user_name = '%s'" cur.execute(sql,(User))
```

to :

```
sql = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE email= '"+ self.Username.get() +"'"
            cur.execute(sql)
```

and it is working as expected.

Comment: This is not safe, as it is open to SQL injections, its recommended to use  parameter substitution instead

Comment: Try something like `c.execute("SELECT password FROM users WHERE user_name = %s", (self.Username.get(),))` i think it will work